# How to configure IntelliJ products WITHOUT editing files in bin?

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, development-environment, configuration-files, intellij-14

I'd like to set some specific options in **`idea.vmoptions`** and **`idea.properties`** for IntelliJ IDEA 14, but I don't have access to those files in `C:\Program Files\...` (yes, that's Windows, don't troll ;)

**Is there a folder in `%UserProfile%` or an environment variable I could set to read those files (both `vmoptions` and `properties`!) from elsewhere?**

Please don't suggest to copy the whole IDEA folder elsewhere, there's a reason why I can't access it. I would be interested in a Linux solution too, the same would most likely work on Windows.

#### My Research

For Mac there're specific instructions at [Increasing Memory Heap](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html), but for Linux and Windows it's just filename which are trivial to find out anyway.

I also found [IntelliJ IDEA files locations](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181), but it says `can be modified in IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties` which doesn't help since I can't access that file, but want to change properties in it.

#### Update: Simple Answer

Create `IDEA_PROPERTIES` and `IDEA_VM_OPTIONS` environment variables and point them to the files you want, restart IDE, done.

Also see [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html) for more (and maybe report that it lacks any mention of `IDEA_PROPERTIES`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `%USERPROFILE%\.IntelliJIdea14\idea%BITS%.exe.vmoptions` on Windows as custom options file. I tried it and it works.
Another way that I haven't tried, but I think should work, is to copy idea.bat and edit it to use the file you need.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice the .bat file which tells me all the answers, that is to use `IDEA_PROPERTIES` and `IDEA_VM_OPTIONS` environment variables to specify the full path of those files.

Comment: After finding the right answer it puzzles me that searching for these yield no official documentation... nor any honorable mentions, I'm sad.

Comment: @twisterrob The documentation has been updated! :)
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tuning-intellij-idea.html